# Use Javascript to find an element's attribute value can found in a list and add a class to some of its children if the value is present?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to hide some entries in a forum page if they are made by users I don't like, and they way to do it is to find an outer div which matches

A forum I'm on has come under attack by users who want to destroy them by flooding them with irrelevant images, and the moderator cannot cope with the onslaught.

I'm want to get round that problem by filtering out images if they come from certain users.

The posts are enclosed in an outer div whith contains the user name.

```
div[poster-name="spam_imager"] > a.thumbnail {
    visibility:hidden;
    /* display: none; (an alternative) */

}

div[poster-name="spam_imager"]  img.preview {
    visibility:hidden;
    /* display: none; (an alternative) */
}
```

But it won't scale up as many users have to be added, so the function has to check if the value of `poster-name` attribute is present in the list, and then look for a child image with the `preview` or a child link with the `thumbnail`class then add `spam_image_block` to the class.

That way two rules will suffice:

```
a.spam_image_block {
    visibility:hidden;
    /* display: none; (an alternative) */
}


img.spam_image_block {
    visibility:hidden;
    /* display: none; (an alternative) */
}
```

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('div[poster-name]').forEach(div => { if (list.includes(this.getAttribute('poster-name'))) this.querySelector('img').style.display = "none"; });`

Comment: @ChrisG Now I've got to dredge up my old Greasemonkey skills and scripts and see how to get going. The list has to be loaded from somewhere and be updated as well. Thanks.

Comment: They bro i don't think that you provide enough information you just described the problem and added some CSS who isn't helpful to check it at all your post nearly wants us to made that code for you not just help you solve a problem and that's not free like you are stuck in problem and described it well and provided everything help to fix it i think this post should to closed or improved to get more details

Comment: @ChrisG When I try it I get the error message `TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function`

Comment: Right, replace `this` with `div` (in both places)

Comment: @ChrisG I managed to get it working Thx. How can I search for an image with particular classes? I want to set the attributes of an image with <img class="res-image-media res-media-zoomable" ...>` within the div but somehow I can't seem to get the syntax right. Does `querySelector` direct child items, or does it select at child any level?

Comment: It selects anything inside the element it's called on. You need something like `div.querySelector("img.res-image-zoomable")` for instance. The selector string works exactly like CSS selectors.

Comment: @ChrisG The element in question is hidden in the DOM until a button reveals it. So I have to disable the button. Thx

Comment: @JS_INF I have a rough idea of what I need to do, but the Javascript and CSS syntax are not that obvious

Comment: Why do you want to hide something that isn't visible anyway? Are you trying to keep yourself from looking at these images...? Anyway, just remove the buttons instead. Why not google something like "remove element from DOM" and come up with a solution? I helped you because you had 17k rep but this is turning into a JS 101 tutorial...

Comment: @ChrisG Will you make you comment into an answer so I can mark it answered?

Comment: That's okay, I'm not here for cheap rep

Answer (score 0):

This needs a practical solution, based on preventing the user from uploading a specific number of images, in terms of allowing and disallowing, I suggest sending the value of the user's permission to be true or false with the basic data on loading the page to JavaScript to configure the download button or not , and I do not recommend relying on CSS to do this , because it is very easy to change it from the browser, whatever the method used for it

Comment: OP is not maintaining the forum, they're just a user there.

Comment: By the same principle, I think that the images and the rest of the components that you want to prevent and show are created from data coming from the databases and organized by a script, whatever the language of the server used in it. I also think that you filter that data before authorizing it to this script

Comment: It is as @ChrisG says

Comment: I think @MohamedElAzazy is a bot. 3 years on stackoverflow with only 9 points. I'm sorry but the internet has been flooded with too many of them of late.

Comment: Thank you, you're right, I'm really a little bit involved, and I'm trying to increase it as much as I can, sorry for that